# MVP question, a presenter needs to update a view that it doesn't "own"

Tags: winforms, mvp

I have two presenters, and each of them has a view.

Presenter A's view has a grid.  When one clicks on one of the rows, the specific row entity is opened in Presenter B's view (this consits of a a few text boxes in a new window.)

The "B" view has a "Save" button, which would close the window and return you to the "A" grid.  I want the "A" grid to automatically refresh when this happens.

I can do it by passing a reference of presenter A to presenter B, but I'm not sure whether this is the preferred way of doing this kind of communication.

Please advise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  think, there is nothing wrong if Presenter A has a reference of Presenter B. According to what you have described, view B is a child view to view A.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as the accepted one.  I've solved this by using an event. As Presenter A is instantiating presenter B, it now listens for an event that will be raised by B whenever the record is saved.  It seems like a clean way of doing this.